# Location of WAL in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have enabled WAL for my Structured Streaming Application. Where do I find the location of WAL logs?
I am able to see WAL for my Spark streaming process in the prefix **receivedBlockMetadata** . But, I don't see any prefix created for Structured Streaming

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding, WAL only works in spark streaming, not structred streaming.
Structured streaming implements fault tolerance based on checkpoint like flink global state. The checkpoint stores all the state including kafka offsets and others.The location is specified in your code .

Comment: The system ensures end-to-end exactly-once fault-tolerance guarantees through checkpointing and Write-Ahead Logs. In short, Structured Streaming provides fast, scalable, fault-tolerant, end-to-end exactly-once stream processing without the user having to reason about streaming.
Ref: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html

Comment: I think the person who put -1 to this guy, just understand him wrong.
Structure streaming doesn't use WAL from DStream, which means it does not write every record from receiver to stream. Spark Structure stream writes a every batch metadata in it's own WALs, offset and commit logs. Please take a look on org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution -> offsetLog,commitLog val.

Answer (score 1):

In Spark Structure Streaming, now WAL with every message from the receiver.
Only two logs with metadata for every batch: offset and commit logs.
You can find details of implementation in `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution`. ->

```
/**
   * A write-ahead-log that records the offsets that are present in each batch. In order to ensure
   * that a given batch will always consist of the same data, we write to this log *before* any
   * processing is done.  Thus, the Nth record in this log indicated data that is currently being
   * processed and the N-1th entry indicates which offsets have been durably committed to the sink.
   */
  val offsetLog = new OffsetSeqLog(sparkSession, checkpointFile("offsets"))

  /**
   * A log that records the batch ids that have completed. This is used to check if a batch was
   * fully processed, and its output was committed to the sink, hence no need to process it again.
   * This is used (for instance) during restart, to help identify which batch to run next.
   */
  val commitLog = new CommitLog(sparkSession, checkpointFile("commits"))
```

Both of them available in a `checkpointLocation` in folder offsets and commits.
In Structure Streaming logs contain only offset information.